# LINQ Expressions Body ToString

Tags: regex, string, linq, lambda

I'm wondering if somebody can explain to me the downside of retrieving

```
(Expression<Func<T, bool>>) Expression.Body
```

at runtime and operating on this as a string?

for example given the following

```
public partial class Tests : Form
{
    public Tests()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        textBox1.Text = t.Evaluate(templates => templates.usable == true && templates.name == "tc1");
    }       
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool usable { get; set; }
}

public static class Helpers
{
    public static string Evaluate<T>(this T input,Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression) where T : class
    {

        return Expression.Parameters.Single().Name + " " + Expression.Body;

    }
}
```

which returns

```
templates ((templates.usable == True) AndAlso (templates.name == "tc1"))
```

**I'm wondering what sort of performance issues may arise from retrieving this and then parsing it through a Regex expression**

in answer to the question why? I've been playing around with Dapper a bit, but none of the pre existing extensions (that I've seen) appeal to me

I would like to be able to operate on it in a similar fashion to EF for example

```
_repo.Select(templates=>templates.usable== true && templates.id == templateId);
```

Comment: There surely can't be a downside to retrieving a string, and operating on a string. The potential downside is going to be when you try and deal with the *resulting* string as a piece of structured data. When you parse it, what are you going to do with the result that you can't do with the `Expression` itself?

Comment: (templates.usable == True) AndAlso (templates.name == "tc1") is quite similar to (templates.usable = True) And (templates.name = "tc1") which can be used as the where statement in a select statement. In the case of (templates=>templates.usable== true && templates.id == templateId) it should have been (templates=>templates.usable== true && templates.id == id) which is similar to (templates.usable= true AND templates.id = @id)

templates is also the name of the table to be queried. so the idea is to "swap" == for =, andalso for and etc

Comment: My point is, whatever information you are going to extract from its *text representation* is already in the `Expression` itself, so you'd be better off interrogating *that* rather than having to parse text. I haven't myself looked at the whole expression visitor stuff (on the todo list!) but there are resources around when you google for expression trees and expression visitor, [arbitrary example](http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/building-expression-evaluator-with-expression-trees-in-csharp-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks - the reason I hadn't is that I probably didn't really understand the nature of expression trees from the examples I'd seen - this example led me to a starting point that I could follow.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nudge towards using the actual expression rather than parsing the text.
for anybody that's interested I've posted a link to the first draft of my sqlexpression project.[Google Code - SqlExpression.cs](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressions/source/browse/trunk/sqlexpression.cs)

The parameters that are created are DynamicParameters from Dapper but could easily be swapped for a standard sql parameter

haven't done alot of testing yet but query appears to perform reasonably well at this stage